# Remove files from phone that won't boot

Tags: data-recovery, htc-vivid

I have an HTC Vivid that, when turned on, fails to load. The screen is white with the HTC logo, but it never moves any further than that. There are pictures on this phone that I'd like to save, but I can't connect it to the computer since the USB debugging won't work since I can't get past the boot screen.

Is there any way to recover these images? I'm not concerned about damaging the phone or voiding the warranty (there isn't one), because these pictures are quite important.

EDIT: There is no SD card in the phone, so the data isn't on it. It hasn't been rooted.

When I try to run recovery, it gives me the following errors:

```
E:Can't mount /cache/recovery/command
E:Can't mount /data/data/recovery/log
E:Can't open /data/data/recovery/log
```

Comment: Not an answer, rather thinking aloud: Does it succeed to boot in any mode (recovery, fastboot) that makes it accessible for flashing? Then, maybe, only maybe, you could flash a custom recovery. I never tried, and don't remember the name currently, but there was one including a file manager, or the file manager could be flashed separately. If that would succeed, you could use that to copy your important files from the device to a card, and then take the card and attach it to your PC using a card reader.

Comment: It won't boot in recovery or fastboot. I think it's a lost cause.

Comment: One thing to be tried is a [hard-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-reset/info) (don't confuse this with a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info)): Remove the battery for a minute (optionally longer), then re-insert it and try again. There's a little chance this helps, so it's worth a try (what to lose, anyway?).

Comment: Already tried that as well. It still failed to boot after multiple attempts.

Comment: That seems to leave the service center as last ressort. Trouble is they usually don't care to backup your data. But you could add a big note (stick it to the device with duck tape :) explaining you need the data -- and pray they can read...